# /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 problem on boot?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, swap

Just before the boot logo fades away and the login screen shows, there's a little message that says there was some kind of problem with `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` and I have to press S or M or something, then everything continues as normal and I don't really know what's going on.

So, is anything seriously wrong (because the computer is still functioning fine)?  If so, how do I fix it, and if not, how do I stop the message from showing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen this when I do not set up disk encryption and ubuntu runs under the assumption of why would you not want to?  If you set up the disk encryption it should stop giving this message and say instead that mounting was successful.

Its basically letting whoever is loading the os at the time that the drive is not encrypted.

Is this similar to your situation?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).